# storing special utf characters in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following response from one of the API I am using:

```
\ud83d\udc51 CODE :: davon top\n\ud83d\udc51 MATERIAL :: spandek rayon\n\ud83d\udc51 PRICE :: 70.000\n\nFIX ORDER langsung hubungi contact :\n\ud83d\udc49 LINE : hijabroom\n\ud83d\udc49 PIN BB : 28EFA80B\nRead mekanisme before order!\n\n
```

I wanted to store this inside mysql database, however when I see this in my database it is stored as:

```
? CODE :: davon top
? MATERIAL :: spandek rayon
? PRICE :: 70.000

FIX ORDER langsung hubungi contact :
? LINE : hijabroom
? PIN BB : 28EFA80B
Read mekanisme before order!
```

the table is set as the following configurations:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not necessarily doing anything wrong; the behavior you describe is the behavior we expect, because MySQL `utf8` characterset only supports characters in Basic Multilingual Plane, does not support supplementary characters.

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509668/iphone-emoticons-insert-into-mysql-but-become-blank-value/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `utf8` characterset supports only BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), code points `U+0000` thru `U+D7FF`.

The unicode points you show (`U+D83D` and `U+DC51`) form a surrogate pair, used to encode a supplementary character.  From the MySQL documentation regarding **utf8** support:

**No support for supplementary characters (BMP characters only).**

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

(The reason you're getting the question mark is because that's the default character for code points that can't be translated.)

---

MySQL 5.5 introduced **utf8mb4** characterset, which is capable of storing supplementary characters.