# iOS emoticons not stored correctly in MySQL

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, utf-8

I'm developing a chat app for `iOS` and I'm trying to store the chat text in a `MySQL` database. Normal text works proper, even special chars like german 'umlaute'. I'm sending the text as Json to the server.

What not works is if I use emoticons from the `iOS` emoticons keyboard, like this:

```
{"userid":"1","message":"Test 123 ⚽️❤️"}
```

I first had the `MySQL` database tables as `UTF-8`. The result was that the chars: `"Test 123 ⚽️❤️"` got stored and the other emoticons got truncated. I have to add I saw the full string like above in the `PHP` log, so it seems not to be an issue that `PHP` does not receive it correctly. This is how it looks in the php log:

```
INFO  - 2014-12-16 22:25:04 --> New Feed Post. Json: {"userid":"1","message":"Djjdhd"}
```

The issue is that `MySQL` does not store it correctly. I changed the whole database to `UTF-16` and even `UTF-32` as I thought those chars are not in the `UTF-8` range but in the `UTF-16` range.

Result was that the emoticons get not truncated yet, but appear as question marks in the database, like this:

```
"Test 123 ⚽️❤️????????????"
```

Any idea why these emoticons do not get stored proper?

I saw this post ([iPhone emoticons insert into MySQL but become blank value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509668/iphone-emoticons-insert-into-mysql-but-become-blank-value)) but it appears that `PHP` receives it correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to make sure the SAME charset is used through the ENTIRE rendering pipeline. you've forgotten something, somewhere, e.g. the php->mysql connection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Ahhh thanks! It was CodeIgniter being set to UTF-8 in the database config file. I set it to UTF-16 and it works. Thanks Marc, the second posting was the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

I've solved a similar problem setting up the table and column to `utf8mb4`:

For each table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_with_emojis CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

And each of the columns of that tables:

```
ALTER TABLE table_with_emojis CHANGE column_with_emojis VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

As it is explained in this post http://blog.arkency.com/2015/05/how-to-store-emoji-in-a-rails-app-with-a-mysql-database/ (it is for Ruby on Rails but you can apply it to PHP).

There is a excellent answer at SO with much more details and other possible problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/2412686

**As [walapu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275014/walapu) has commented, be careful if you already have an emoji at your database** (it wasn't my case as I couldn't store any emoji before)

Comment: CAUTION: If you currently have emojis stored, THIS WILL CORRUPT ALL OF YOUR EMOJI DATA.

Comment: Thank you walapu, I've added a notice at the answer